# app crashes when getting a reference on android studio

Tags: java, android, crash

I'm a newbie in programming and stuff.. I'm using the android-youtube-player package from [Pierfrancesco Soffritti](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti).. and when I try to Get a reference to YouTubePlayer and run the app it crashes..
`

```
package com.example.youtuuuuuuuuuuuuuuube;

import androidx.annotation.LayoutRes;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.listeners.AbstractYouTubePlayerListener;
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.listeners.YouTubePlayerListener;
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.options.IFramePlayerOptions;
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView;
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.ui.DefaultPlayerUiController;
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.ui.PlayerUiController;
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.ui.menu.YouTubePlayerMenu;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer;
    private YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void playvideo(View v){
        youTubePlayer.loadVideo("S0Q4gqBUs7c", 1f);
    }
}
```

`

my XML code

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/youtube_player_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    app:videoId="S0Q4gqBUs7c"
    app:autoPlay="true"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="playvideo"
    android:text="Button" />
```

I tried to get the reference using OnStart() method, added a button but all of that don't work :(

Comment: "app crashes" -- use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with the crash: https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-debug-001.html

Comment: I am not familiar with that video library but, dont you have to instatiate the `youTubePlayere` and e`youTubeplayerView` variables? I guess they are null when you are calling loadVideo in `youTubePlayer`, can you please add all the code?

Comment: @MarcosNarvaez I'm sorry.. I'm not so familiar yet with programming terms :( so I don't understand what "instantiating a variable" means.. but anyway I add my XML code above as well.

Comment: @Diaa I guess you should have something like `youTubePlayer = new YouTubePlayer();` I think you are calling `youTubePlayer.loadVideo("S0Q4gqBUs7c", 1f);` on a null variable. In the [docs](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player#quick-start) there is a brief description

Comment: @MarcosNarvaez I've read the docs multiple times back and forth.. I really don't understand most of these things.. but that's ok, it's probably too early for me to get engaged into these stuff.. so I'm going to stop stressing about it.. thank you so much for your help.